# Is it possible to create an AWS::Lambda::Version for a set of Lambdas in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

As per title. 
I saw that https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-version.html syntax allows to specify a version for one lambda.
I would like to version all the lambdas that are behind my API Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Version applies to particular Lambda function. If you want to create version for multiple Lambdas you need to define version resource for each of the functions (they can have same version name, but each as a separate resource).